# pgfmathanglebetweenpoints always returns 90

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code and I expect the resulting angle to be 135 degrees but whatevet I try, I get 90.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (1,0);
\coordinate (B) at (-1,1);

\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{A}{B}
\edef\angleAB{\pgfmathresult}
\node at (0,0) {\angleAB};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also tried the following command without knowing what it means, it also prints 90 except one case. The only working case is when A=(1,0) and B=(-1,0), which it prints 180.

```
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}
```

Why is that? Couldn't find any reference document for "pgfmathanglebetweenpoints" by the way, that's why I am asking here.

EDIT: B is corrected from (-1,-1) to (-1,1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` expects, as the name suggests, arguments that expand to x and y coordinates and not node names (`coordinate` is a `node` shape with a single anchor) since those have to be processed with `pgf@process` and so on.

Your second command is on the right track, with `\pgfpointanchor` you can extract a point (in this case the center) from a coordinate. Both are described in the [TikZ/PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).

The following should work (note that the angle between (1,0) and (-1,-1) is 206 (or 154) and not 135):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (1,0);
\coordinate (B) at (-1,-1);
\coordinate (C) at (0,1);

% draw and node for illustration purposes only, not necessary for computation
\draw[->] (A) -- (B);
\draw[->] (A) -- (C);

\node[fill=white] (An) at (1,0) {A};
\node[fill=white] (Bn) at (-1,-1) {B};
\node[fill=white] (Cn) at (0,1) {C};

\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{B}{center}}
\edef\angleAB{\pgfmathresult}
\node at (3,0) {A-B \angleAB};
\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{C}{center}}
\edef\angleAC{\pgfmathresult}
\node at (3,1) {A-C \angleAC};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]