# How does `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` work?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to understand how `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` works. Why here it turns out that X = 243.57? Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{-1cm}{-1cm}}
\edef\angleX{\pgfmathresult}
\node at (3,0) {X=\angleX};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pgfmathanglebetweenpoints always returns 90](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287393/pgfmathanglebetweenpoints-always-returns-90)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pgfmanual v 3.1.5 says on p. 1045 that

[image]

so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,draw,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=#1}]

\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpoint{0cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{-1cm}{-1cm}}
\edef\angleX{\pgfmathresult}
\draw (-1,-1) coordinate[bullet={below:$q$}] -- (0,1) coordinate[bullet={above:$p$}] -- ++ (1,0) 
 arc[start angle=0,end angle=\angleX,radius=1]
 node[midway,above=1ex]{$\alpha=\pgfmathprintnumber{\angleX}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, you were loading `calc` but not using it. You can use it as an alternative to measure the angle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,draw,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=#1}]

\draw (-1,-1) coordinate[bullet={below:$q$}] -- (0,1) coordinate[bullet={above:$p$}] -- ++ (1,0) 
 let \p1=($(0,1)-(-1,-1)$),\n1={180+atan2(\y1,\x1)} in
 arc[start angle=0,end angle=\n1,radius=1]
 node[midway,above=1ex]
 {$\alpha=\pgfmathparse{\n1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand this phrase  "to a line going straight right from <p>" from the pgfmanual.

Comment: FWIW, I don't., really. `p` is utterly irrelevant for that part of the sentence: you get the angle of p-q over the x-axis.

Comment: @Raphael Well, your statement can be misinterpreted, but what you mean to say is correct, of course.