# Can a PGF function get a coordinate as an argument?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I would like to use coordinates as arguments to a PGF function. Specifically, calculating the angle between two vectors (via the dot product).

Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (u) at (1,3);
  \coordinate (v) at (3,2);
  \pfgmathsetmacro{\th}{angle(u,v)}

  % Some drawing that uses this angle
  % ...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: You could use `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287393/pgfmathanglebetweenpoints-always-returns-90?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

Since you are saying that you want to use the angle in some path, I'd like to recommend the `calc` library which is made for this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (u) at (1,3);
  \coordinate (v) at (3,2);
  \draw (u) -- (0,0) -- (v);
  \draw let
  \p1=($(u)-(0,0)$),\p2=($(v)-(0,0)$),\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)}
  in (\n1:1) arc[start angle=\n1,end angle=\n2,radius=1]
  coordinate[midway] (aux)
  (3,4) node[right](a){the angle is \pgfmathparse{\n2-\n1}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult}
  (a.south west) edge[-stealth,out=-135,in={0.5*\n1+0.5*\n2}] (aux);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, `atan2` is used to compute the slope angles of the lines, and the difference between the angles is the angle enclosed by the lines. Of course, ordering is important, i.e. you can get the opposite sign if you use the opposite conventions.

The `-(0,0)` in `($(v)-(0,0)$)` is added under the assumption that you want to measure the angles between the lines connecting `v` (or `u`) to the origin, and it is necessary if you are in a scope that got shifted, say.

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks :)