# How to distribute edges on a node's border evenly in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the figure below, I achieve an even distribution of the three curved edges on the border of node 3 by doing quite some math manually. This is cumbersome and inflexible. Is there a short and easy solution to let TikZ do the even distribution automatically?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle] (1) at (0, 0) {1};
\node [circle] (2) at (1,-3) {2};
\node [circle] (3) at (5,-2) {3};
\node [circle] (4) at (4, 1) {4};
\path (1) edge (2) (2) edge (3) (3) edge (4) (4) edge (1);

\path (4) edge [out=-100, in=129.835] (3); % These in values
\path (1) edge [out=-20,  in=151.236] (3); % are computed
\path (2) edge [out=20,   in=172.636] (3); % manually, yuk!
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One idea of mine was to create an invisible circular arc between the point on the border of 3 where the straight lines touch, then create the start/ending points of the curved arcs by placing coordinates on that circular arc with `[pos=0.25]`, `[pos=0.5]`, and `[pos=0.75]`. However, I'm not sure if that is the cleanest solution because requires the creation of a number of helper elements and (more importantly) I have no idea how to retrieve the points on the border of 3 where the straight lines from 4 and 2 touch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a solution based on the `pgf` commands `\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints` and `\pgfmathanglebetweenlines` defined on page 1047 of the manual).  For example, the angle determined by the points *B*, *A*, and *D* in this order (`\angleBAD` in the code below) together with the angle formed by the vector *AB* and the horizontal axis (`\argAB` in the code) allows us to find the angles you are looking for as `\argAB+k*\angleBAD/4` with *k=1,2,3*.

In the drawing, your construction is grayed and is there for comparison.  I decided, for coherence, that the inner edges must bisect the angles *B*, *C*, and *D*.
[image]

**The code**
(the local commands `\computearg` and `angle` are based on @percusse 's answer [pgfmathanglebetweenpoints always returns 90](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287393/pgfmathanglebetweenpoints-always-returns-90))

```
\documentclass[margin=.3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\newcommand{\computearg}[2]{\pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}}
\newcommand{\computeangle}[3]{\pgfmathanglebetweenlines{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#2}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{#3}{center}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[circle] (C) at (0, 0) {C};
  \node[circle] (D) at (1, -3) {D};
  \node[circle] (A) at (5, -2) {A};
  \node[circle] (B) at (4, 1) {B};
  \path (C) edge (D) (D) edge (A) (A) edge (B) (B) edge (C);

  \computearg{A}{B}
  \edef\argAB{\pgfmathresult}
  \computearg{B}{C}
  \edef\argBC{\pgfmathresult}
  \computearg{C}{D}
  \edef\argCD{\pgfmathresult}
  \computearg{D}{A}
  \edef\argDA{\pgfmathresult}
  \computeangle{B}{A}{D}
  \edef\angleBAD{\pgfmathresult}
  \computeangle{C}{B}{A}
  \edef\angleCBA{\pgfmathresult}
  \computeangle{D}{C}{B}
  \edef\angleDCB{\pgfmathresult}
  \computeangle{A}{D}{C}
  \edef\angleADC{\pgfmathresult}

  \path[red, thick]
  (A) edge[out={\argAB+\angleBAD/4}, in={\argBC+\angleCBA/2}] (B)
  (A) edge[out={\argAB+\angleBAD/2}, in={\argCD+\angleDCB/2}] (C)
  (A) edge[out={\argAB+3*\angleBAD/4}, in={\argDA+\angleADC/2}] (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```